# Alternative URL for library item

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

I have a library of PDF documents that includes a column for the project associated with each document. The project id is unique within the library and I want to create a URL that uses this project id to reference the appropriate document. This is needed for creating a link to the document from a workflow that runs on a different library. Is it possible to create a URL in this way?

Comment: If you only want the link to the item instead of document, you can use: `http://siteUrl/libraryName/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=ProjID&FilterValue1=projIdValue`

Comment: Thanks uberz91, I think that will be sufficient and not something I had considered. Put your comment in an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this URL to get the item:
 `http://siteUrl/libraryName/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=ProjID&FilterValue1‌​=projIdValue`